# Create new object from existing object with properies setted in array in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have existing object like that:

```
let origObj = {
   name: 'John',
   surname: 'Doe',
   age: 23,
   gender: 'M'
}
```

i want to create a new object with properties, setted in array

```
let fieldsList = ['name', 'gender'];
```

New object could be look like this:

```
newObj = {
   name: 'John',
   gender: 'M'
}
```

I answered to my question below, but maybe you have a better solutions to solve this, e.g. using ES6 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce`.

```js
let origObj = {
   name: 'John',
   surname: 'Doe',
   age: 23,
   gender: 'M'
}

let fieldsList = ['name', 'gender'];

var newObject = fieldsList.reduce((obj,prop) => {
return obj[prop]= origObj[prop], obj 
} ,{});

console.log(newObject);
```